# Show/Hide table row div on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an invoice.php that is loading a table from another page.  The table looks like this for instance:

```
 <table id="invoice_table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
             Item
        </th>
        <th>
             Description
        </th>
        <th>
             Delivered
        </th>
        <th>
             #
        </th>
        <th>
             Item Price
        </th>
        <th>
             Total
        </th>
        <th>
             Purchase Total
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
<tr class="service" data-inv_services_id="121">
            <td>
                 Service
                 <br/><br/>
                 <div class="items_buttons" style="display:none">
                 <button type="button" data-deleteID="121" data-table="invoice_services" class="edit_service edit_button btn btn-xs default">
                 <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                 </button>

                 <button type="button" data-deleteID="121" data-table="invoice_services" class="delete_button btn btn-xs default">
                 <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                 </button>
                 </div>
            </td>
            <td>Drop Shipment Charge<br/><strong>Taxable:</strong> N</td>
            <td id="service_delivery_date"></td>
            <td id="service_quantity">1</td>
            <td id="service_item_price">$15.00</td>
            <td id="service_total">$15.00</td>
            <td id="service_purchase_price">$15.00</td>
        </tr>
 <tr class="payment" data-inv_payments_id="1383">
            <td>
                 Payment
                 <br/><br/>
                 <div class="items_buttons" style="display:none">
                 <button type="button" data-deleteID="1383" data-table="invoice_payments" class="edit_payment edit_button btn btn-xs default">
                 <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                 </button>

                 <button type="button" data-deleteID="1383" data-table="invoice_payments" class="delete_button btn btn-xs default">
                 <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                 </button>
                 </div>
            </td>
            <td>check</td>
            <td id="payment_entered_date">2016-05-12</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="payment_amount_paid">$15.00</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Each row has a hidden tools button div:

```
 <div class="items_buttons" style="display:none">
                 <button type="button" data-deleteID="121" data-table="invoice_services" class="edit_service edit_button btn btn-xs default">
                 <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                 </button>

                 <button type="button" data-deleteID="121" data-table="invoice_services" class="delete_button btn btn-xs default">
                 <i class="icon-trash"></i>
              </button>
   </div>
```

On my main invoice.php page I am trying to use JQuery to show the items_buttons div as the user's mouse hovers over each row.  Then hide that row's buttons when the mouse leaves that row.

I am working on this:

```
 $('#invoice_table').on({

    mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
        $(this).find('div.item_buttons').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
          $(this).find('div.item_buttons').hide();
    }

});
```

But that doesn't work.  I tried .hover but it doesn't work for the table that is loaded into the page through jQuery.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

> it doesn't work for the table that is loaded into the page through jQuery

You are probably attaching the event after the table is loaded into the DOM.  Therefore you want to [delegate the event](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) so it's attached to a parent element which exists.  For example:

```
 $(document).on('hover', '#invoice_table tr', function() { ... });
```

(It's better to attach the event to the parent element of `#invoice_table`, but this is a working example.)

Comment: Thanks.  How is this:      $("#invoice_table").on("hover", "tr", function(e) {
          if(e.type == "mouseenter") {
            console.log("over");
            $(this).find('.items_buttons').show();
          }
          else if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
            console.log("out");
            $(this).find('.items_buttons').hide();
          }
    });

Comment: I also was targeting the wrong class.   I forgot I named the class itemS_buttons not item_buttons.  The code above works though.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to add a mouse hover handler to each table raw:

```
function mouseInHandler(){
    $(this).find(".items_buttons").show();
};
function mouseOutHandler(){
    $(this).find(".items_buttons").hide();
};
$('tr').hover(mouseInHandler,mouseOutHandler);
```